# Importing users from a xls file in WS2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

How do I import users that is in a xls file into my Active Directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could export the XLS file from Excel as a CSV and then use the addusers.exe utility to import the CSV into Active Directory: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199878

Comment: The users are premade in a xls file, I dont have them in my AD.

Comment: I've edit the answer to clarify but I meant that you should export the XLS file from Excel to a CSV (in the correct format) and then use addusers.exe to add it to the AD.

Comment: How do I export the XLS file to a CSV?

Comment: http://excel.tips.net/Pages/T002483_Creating_a_CSV_File.html